# Create new Object() in catch block js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, winston

```
import express from 'express';
import route from './server/routes/route';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import favicon from 'serve-favicon';
import path from 'path';
import Logger from './server/logger/logger.js';

try {
  const app = express();
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '/client/assets/favicon.ico')));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));
  app.use(route);
  app.listen(3000);
  new Logger().logInfo('Server started at port 3000');
} catch (e) {
  new Logger().logError(e);
  process.exit(1);
}

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  process.exit(1);
  new Logger().logError(err);
});
```

Here i am trying to create an express server. I used a try catch block. When i remove the `import path from 'path'` an error is generated and the catch is called. However the problem is `new Logger().logError(e);` not working. it is supposed to log error into a certain file. But nothing is happening. But if there is no error, then the `logInfo()` is working alright. I tried logging to console and it is working. I am using babel so is it a problem with that ?
Logger is a class which contain a winston logger implementation and exposes methods logError and logInfo.

Comment: *"However the problem is `new Logger().logError(e);` not working."* Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: question edited

Comment: It could be that `.logError()` isn't entirely synchronous and `process.exit(1)` interrupts it before it's done

Comment: i removed the `process.exit(1)`  and then the log worked. I tried giving the `process.exit(1)` in the callback for logInfo() but id didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [known bug in winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/228) and it seems they are not going to patch it. I have used one of the workarounds provided there and everything works fine. Here

```
this.winstonlogger.log('error', logMessage, () => {
  this.transports.file.on('flush', () => {
    process.exit(1);
  });
});
```